# Delay class questions (C#)

Tags: c#

I created a static class called "Delay" which basically accepts argument of (double delay, ThreadStart action). Here it is:

```
 public class Delay
{
    public static void Execute(double delay, ThreadStart action)
    {
        Delay.Execute((int)delay, action);
    }

    public static void Execute(int delay, ThreadStart action)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer(delay);

        t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            action();
            t.Dispose();
            t = null;
        });

        t.Start();
    }

    private Timer t;

    public Delay(int delay, ThreadStart action)
    {
        t = new Timer(delay);

        t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (t != null)
            {
                t.Stop();
                action();
                t.Dispose();
            }

            t = null;
        });
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        t.Start();
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.Stop();
            t.Dispose();
        }

        t = null;
    }
}
```

I have a few questions.

1. Is it really bad? My friend told me it'd give me errors for sure, but I haven't experienced any.
2. Is there a way to improve it? It works fine now, but I don't want it to leak memory in the future.

Best regards.

Comment: SO is for specific problems. As it seems you don't have any problems (as your code seems to run fine for you), SO might be the wrong place. This looks more like a question for the folks at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620733/memory-leak-in-c-sharp

Comment: @BastiM I concur with your opinion..

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any of this.Simply you can use async/await feature like:

```
public async Task Execute(double delay, ThreadStart action)
{
    await Task.Delay((int)delay).ContinueWith((x) => action());
}
```

Comment: Delegate System.Action<Task> does not take 0 arguments.

Comment: just change this: `() => action()` to `(x) => action()`

Comment: And how would I use it? My current code is : Delay.Execute(60000, () => SomeMethod()), However, the compiler says that "Because this call is not awaited...".

Comment: It's a warning, you can ignore it or you can make your current method async and await that task like this: `"await Delay.Execute(60000, () => SomeMethod())"`